# How do I setup Alpine to connect my Gmail account using IMAP?

Tags: freebsd, alpine-mail

I am using FreeBSD 8.1 and just installed Alpine email client. I wonder if anybody knows how to setup Alpine to get mail from a Gmail account using IMAP.

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/q/130899/19753

Comment: anyone else getting the wrong X-Google-Original-From  value?

Answer (score 9):

For clarity, I'm just going to give the directions in terms of what you should add to .pinerc.  You can also set all of these setting using the configuration interface if you wish.

To get your mail via IMAP:

```
inbox-path={imap.gmail.com/ssl/user=username@gmail.com}
```

Include this to make sure you have access to all of the various gmail folders:

```
folder-collections=Gmail {imap.gmail.com/ssl/user=username@gmail.com}[]
```

I find this useful to mimic "archiving":

```
default-saved-msg-folder=[Gmail]/All Mail
```

To send mail via gmail, you need this in .pinerc:

```
smtp-server=smtp.gmail.com:587/tls/user=username@gmail.com
```

Also, I find that these two settings improve performance a lot:

```
 rsh-open-timeout=0
 disable-these-authenticators=GSSAPI
```

If you want alpine to remember your password for you, you can run this command in your home directory:

```
 touch .pine-passfile
```

The first time you use alpine after running this command, you will be asked whether you want to save your password for later use each time you enter one.

Comment: My problem now (which I didn't use to experience earlier, soem years ago with such a configuration) is that Gmail shows me a message with a weblink to confirm the login, but alpine (and pine) don't have have enough length for it to fit. I'd appreciate an advice how to read the weblink through Alpine and confirm the login. [Here at reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/2z0r7q/how_to_access_gmail_from_the_command_line_on/cpeplmx), they, too, recommend turning on "less secure" apps in Gmail. I'd rather like an explanation what is wanted by Gmail and how to make an app secure.

Comment: And here is this problem mentioned with Gnus: http://superuser.com/q/963361/65570

Comment: I think the warning about "less secure" is a bit exaggerated. The [Fetchmail FAQ](http://www.fetchmail.info/fetchmail-FAQ.html#I9) has a paragraph about it actually.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you need to set up with Google API and [configure alpine to use xoAuth](https://alpine.x10host.com/alpine/alpine-info/misc/xoauth2.html). It will take you a good hour if doing it for the first time.

The previous answer, involving enabling "less secure" applications in Google account settings, is no longer possible, at least for me, since 2021. I had been setting the "less secure" apps in Gamil to use alpine **for 10 years** now. Since 2021, even if that setting is enabled, Gmail's IMAP server will still try to redirect the user to a web authentication page. This happened to my various Gmail accounts. This is the end of the password authentication era, and now the only way to get alpine to work with Gmail is to go to Settings -> xoaUth2 and try to get xoAuth working. It still technically uses IMAP except for not its authentication part.

Maybe we should be thankful that Gmail has allowed it for 10 years.

Comment: application specific passwords are still a thing on Google... you sure that you can't make that part still work?